# Limit of Function, Taylor Series

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I want to evaluate $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{e^{it}-1-zt}{t^2}$$                                                                  By expanding in Taylor Series and doing the permitted algebraic simplifications (mainly subtracting the $1$ from the taylor expansion of $\cos(t)$ and then canceling one t from the denominator), I obtain $$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(\frac{-t}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{4!} +)... + i(1-\frac{t^2}{3!}-\frac{t^4}{5!}+...)-z}{t}$$ I'd argue that now I'm left with $$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{i-z}{t}$$ which goes to $\infty$. Can you confirm or correct my reasoning?

Comment: The limit exists if $\mathbb C$ iff $z=i$.

Comment: You did not consider that term $-\frac{t}{2!}$, but for $z\ne i$, the limit does not exist anyway. But if $z=i$, the limit is $-\frac{1}{2}$ and not $0$, which would be the result if we use the given limit

Comment: Okay, I get the convergence to $-\frac{1}{2}$ for $ z= i$, but why no limit for $z \neq i$ ? I get  $-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i-z}{t}$. The second summand goes to either $+\infty$ or$-\infty$ right? Is that why?

Answer (score 0):

Put $z=a+ib$. then compute

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\cos(t)-1-at+i(\sin(t)-bt)}{t^2}$$

$$=\lim_{t\to 0}(\frac{-\frac{t^2}{2}-at+it(1-b)}{t^2}+\epsilon(t))$$

- If $b=1$ and $a=0$ then the limit is $\frac{-1}{2}.$
  else, it doesn't exist.